# how to extract images from file and put them in a list using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to create a function that in the input I put a filename and as an output i get all the images in a list.
in this file i have all sorts of documents(text,images ,videos..) and all the images have different extensions.
I wrote this code and it doesn't seem to work

```
def readFileImages(strFolderName):
    print strFolderName
    image_list = []
    st=strFolderName+"*.png"
    for filename in glob.glob(st): #assuming gif
        image_list.append(filename)
    return image_list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure you have a path separator. This is best done using [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.join#os.path.join) to add it for you:

```
import glob    
import os

def readFileImages(strFolderName):
    print strFolderName
    image_list = []
    st = os.path.join(strFolderName, "*.gif")

    for filename in glob.glob(st): #assuming gif
        image_list.append(filename)

    return image_list    

print readFileImages(os.getcwd())   # Use current working directory as example
```

Note, `glob.glob()` already returns a list, so the following would be eqivalent:

```
import glob 
import os   

def readFileImages(strFolderName):
    st = os.path.join(strFolderName, "*.gif")
    return glob.glob(st)

print readFileImages(os.getcwd())
```

The reason why `os.path.join()` is better is that if `strFolderName` does not contain tailing separator, it would be added. If it does have one, an extra one would not be added. Also if you run the script on different operator system, the correct separator would be used automatically. You can see which one would be used by `print os.path.sep`